# how to focus on a particular section in another html or php page while clicking a button?

Tags: php, html

I want to use a search option to find the contents in another page.

My Html page:

```
<form action="search.php" method="post">
<input name="search" type="text"/> 

<input type="image" src="images/search-btn.jpg" alt="search-btn" /> 
</form>
```

I have 5 topics in another page, say 'products.html'. Topic headings are Film, Music, etc.
So if a keyword, like the headings or some predefined keywords in each topic, is typed and search button is clicked I want to redirect to the products.php page.

**The main thing is that i want to get the focus on that particular topic**

Now I'm redirecting simply like this:

```
   <?php
    $val=$_POST['search'];

    if($val=='Music'||$val=='singer')
    {
        header('Location:http://localhost/products.html');
    }

?>
```

Comment: Do you want a server side way to do this or client-side, PHP or JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

page1.html

```
<a name='music'></a><!-- This is anchor -->

<a href='#music'>Go to music on same page</a>
```

page2.html

```
<a href='page1.html#music'>Go to music on another page</a>
```

SERVER SIDE:

```
<?php
    if($val=='Music'||$val=='singer'){
       header("Location:http://localhost/products#$val.html");
    }
?>
```

You can style your keywords anchors as you wish:

`<a name='music'><b>music<b></a>`

```
<span id='music'>music</span>
```

Comment: You can also use `id`'s if you already have them on your page. So `<a href="#music">` will go to the `<h2 id="music">` on a page.

Comment: On server side you need to add code to generate pages with anchors, what is the problem? How can link work on server side if it's browser interface?

Comment: I eddited unswer for your task.

Comment: Thanks DaneSoul... Can i get one more help.. Is it possible to make bold or change the color of that particular keyword to get more focus.?

Comment: I added styling to my unswer. But 'more focus' means only for design issues, as a link this work the same. Btw, useing <a name='music'></a> you can make invisible anchors.

Comment: But i want it to be bold only when the search is using that keyword.

Comment: @arunrc: it's better to accept some unswer in this question and ask another question for that task, because it's completely different solution with own tricks. 

In general: you need to read HASH from URL and change style for element with ID == HASH. But this can be tricky to do it cross-browser compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Within your form post to a page that can deal with the result, save it and then push the user on.

```
<form action="process.php" method="post" name="search">
```

This response page will redirect to something like

```
header("Location: /products.html#music");
```

Depending on how the form was completed.

Then on your products page add ids that tie this up, for example:

```
<h2 id="music">Music</h2>
```

The user will be redirected and the browser will jump to the corresponding anchor or id.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro.. Got it.. Can i get one more help.. Is it possible to make bold or change the color of that particular keyword to get more focus.?

Comment: Do you mean the word they have searched for, or just the title e.g. "music"?

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this technique by using a hidden field, but for the first page JavaScript will work for this

```
<input name="target" type="hidden" value=""/> 
<input name="search" type="text" onkeyup="your-function-to-set-value-on-hidden-field"/>
```

Set the value if typed keyword is matched with your list and on the second page receive the hidden field value in PHP variable and do the stuff.